# Choosing Dense sets

Tags: real-analysis

More than one option can be correct.

> Which of the following sets are dense in $R^2$ with respect to the usual topology.
>
> (a) $\{(x,y)\in R^2:x\in N\}$
>
> (b) $\{(x,y)\in R^2:x+y$ is a rational number$\}$
>
> (c) $\{(x,y)\in R^2:x^2+y^2=5\}$
>
> (d) $\{(x,y)\in R^2:xy\ne0\}$

Natural numbers are not limit points of real numbers. So, (a) is rejected.

Rational numbers can be limit points to irrational numbers, so (b) is selected.

We can draw a circle of radius $\sqrt5$ anywhere in the plane. So, I assume every point can be covered by this circle. So I would say it is also a dense set. If it is not then **which set of points is it not covering?**

$xy=c$ is a hyperbola with coordinate axes as its asymptotes. So, it will not cover all the points of the plane. So, (d) is rejected.

But answer is given as (b) and (d).

Comment: The circle has $(0,0)$ as center. So it cannot be drawn anywhere you like.

Comment: For (d), note that there is no fixed constant $c$.

Comment: @drhab- Thanks. Now I feel like a fool to have asked it at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers to (a) and (b) are correct, but your reasons aren’t really sufficient, especially for (b). I’ll come back to those.

The set in (c) is specifically the circle of radius $\sqrt5$ **centred at the origin**: it’s a closed set in $\Bbb R^2$, and it’s not all of $\Bbb R^2$, so it cannot be dense in $\Bbb R^2$.

The set in (d) contains every point $\langle x,y\rangle$ such that $x\ne 0$ and $y\ne 0$: that’s the whole plane except the coordinate axes. Every point on the coordinate axes is the limit of a sequence from this set, so the closure of this set is $\Bbb R^2$, and this set is therefore dense in $\Bbb R^2$.

The points of (b) are the ones that lie on lines with slope $-1$ and rational $x$- and $y$-intercepts. This set is dense in $\Bbb R^2$, but in order to show that you must show that its closure is all of $\Bbb R^2$; it’s not enough to say that the rationals are dense in the reals.

Finally, the set in (a) is $\Bbb N\times\Bbb R$; since $\Bbb N$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, this set is closed in $\Bbb R^2$. It clearly isn’t all of $\Bbb R^2$, so it cannot be dense in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: For (b) it is I think easier to point out that it is a superset of the dense set $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Sir, how did we decide on the slope to be $-1?$

Comment: @Michael: I’d say rather that that’s probably the easiest way to see that its closure is $\Bbb R^2$ (or whatever equivalent definition of *dense* is being used). But yes, I agree that that’s about as simple as anything.

Comment: @Ramit: The points lie on the lines whose equations are $x+y=q$ for $q\in\Bbb Q$; all lines of the form $x+y=k$ have slope $-1$, as you can see by rewriting the equation as $y=-x+k$.

Comment: My bad, I should have used a little brain. One more question regarding sufficiency condition. Say, it's just given that x and y are rational. Will that set be dense? Now I think No, because irrational numbers are not limit points to rationals. Now I wish Sir, if you could provide more details as to why (b) is dense. (now that I've realised my earlier way of testing was wrong.)

Comment: @Ramit: Yes, it will. The rationals **are** dense in $\Bbb R$: every real number is the limit of a sequence of rationals. From this it’s easy to check that $\Bbb Q^2$ is dense in $\Bbb R^2$, and as Michael Greinecker noted, the set in (b) contains $\Bbb Q^2$ and must therefore also be dense in $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Option (c) cannot possibly be a dense set since it is bounded. For example, its intersection with the non-empty *open* set $\;\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\;;\; (x-10)^2+(y-10)^2<1\}\;$  is the empty set...

And (d) is **not** a hyperbola but, in fact, the union of *all* the possible hyperbolas on the plane! Or, in other words, (d) d is the set of all points on the plane which are not on any of the two axis. It intersects *every* non-empty open set in the planes and it is thus dense there.